# Development workflow for Wordpress using git - issues with plugins and bloginfo('wpurl')

Tags: plugins, git

I'm going with [this git workflow](http://davidwinter.me/articles/2012/04/09/install-and-manage-wordpress-with-git/) for my current wordpress project which I'm running locally using `MAMP`. It allows me to separate the WP core files from the theme and plugin folders using submodules, which is great. My `wp-config` has some extra entries to tell Wordpress where the core files are and where the theme folders are:

```
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wordpress/');

define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/core');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/core/wordpress');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', realpath(ABSPATH . '../wp-content/'));
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', WP_HOME . '/wp-content');
define('UPLOADS', '../wp-content/uploads');
```

My structure from the site root looks like:

```
-wordpress (contains core files)
-wp-content
    -themes
    -plugins
    -uploads
-wp-config.php
```

So my home url is: `http://localhost:8888/core/`

The issues I'm running into all over is with the plugins. Some of them are using `get_bloginfo('wpurl')` to load assets. So an example of that would look like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/core/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/{PLUGIN}/images/{PLUGIN_IMAGE}.png
```

where it should actually be:

```
http://localhost:8888/core/wp-content/plugins/{PLUGIN}/images/{PLUGIN_IMAGE}.png
```

Can I override this somehow without modifying the plugins individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bloginfo`/`get_bloginfo` use [`site_url` to retrieve the `wpurl` value](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/general-template.php#L415), `site_url` provides the [`site_url`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1977) filter, so you should be able to use that filter to alter the output.

```
function alter_site_url_wpse_107701($url) {
  return str_replace('/core/wordpress','/core',$url);
}
add_filter('site_url','alter_site_url_wpse_107701');
```

I am guessing a bit at exactly what you need to replace, but I think that is close.

Comment: This is what I was looking for pretty much. I only need it to override for plugins, otherwise it will override my whole site. The plugins are the only area causing problems currently.

Comment: With that, you can only control the part of the address returned by `site_url`, which isn't the entire string. I don't know that you can restrict that only to plugins. I'd have to do some research.